# Can't Get IIS Log Group in CloudWatch Log Console. After creating Association

Tags: iis, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I try to analysis IIS logs using aws CloudWatch. I followed the procedure as below link
[ https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/automate-iis-and-httperr-logs-to-amazon-cloudwatch-using-ec2-systems-manager/ ]

**Steps followed:**

> 1. Set up the configuration json file.

**Configuration json file:**

`{
    "IsEnabled": true,
    "EngineConfiguration": {
        "PollInterval": "00:00:15",
        "Components": [
            {
                "Id": "SystemEventLog",
                "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.EventLog.EventLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
                "Parameters": {
                    "LogName": "System",
                    "Levels": "7"
                }
            },
            {
                "Id": "SecurityEventLog",
                "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.EventLog.EventLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
                "Parameters": {
                    "LogName": "Security",
                    "Levels": "7"
                }
            },
            {
                "Id": "ETW",
                "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.EventLog.EventLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
                "Parameters": {
                    "LogName": "Microsoft-Windows-WinINet/Analytic",
                    "Levels": "7"
                }
            },
            {
                "Id": "IISLogs",
                "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CustomLog.CustomLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
                "Parameters": {
                    "LogDirectoryPath": "C:\\inetpub\\logs\\LogFiles\\W3SVC1",
                    "TimestampFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                    "Encoding": "UTF-8",
                    "Filter": "",
                    "CultureName": "en-US",
                    "TimeZoneKind": "UTC",
                    "LineCount": "3"
                }
            },
            {
                "Id": "HttpErr",
                "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CustomLog.CustomLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
                "Parameters": {
                    "LogDirectoryPath": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\LogFiles\\HTTPERR",
                    "TimestampFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                    "Encoding": "UTF-8",
                    "Filter": "",
                    "CultureName": "en-US",
                    "TimeZoneKind": "UTC",
                    "LineCount": "3"
                }
            },
            {
                "Id": "CustomLogs",
                "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CustomLog.CustomLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
                "Parameters": {
                    "LogDirectoryPath": "C:\\CustomLogs\\",
                    "TimestampFormat": "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                    "Encoding": "UTF-8",
                    "Filter": "",
                    "CultureName": "en-US",
                    "TimeZoneKind": "Local"
                }
            },
            {
                "Id": "PerformanceCounter",
                "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.PerformanceCounterComponent.PerformanceCounterInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
                "Parameters": {
                    "CategoryName": "Memory",
                    "CounterName": "Available MBytes",
                    "InstanceName": "",
                    "MetricName": "Memory",
                    "Unit": "Megabytes",
                    "DimensionName": "",
                    "DimensionValue": ""
                }
            },
            {
                "Id": "IISCloudWatchLogs",
                "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CloudWatchLogsOutput,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
                "Parameters": {
                    "AccessKey": "---------------------------------",
                    "SecretKey": "----------------------------------",
                    "Region": "us-east-1a",
                    "LogGroup": "RWEBAPP-SERVER",
                    "LogStream": "used our instance id"
                }
            },
            {
                "Id": "HttpErrCloudWatchLogs",
                "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CloudWatchLogsOutput,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
                "Parameters": {
                    "AccessKey": "-----------------------------------------",
                    "SecretKey": "-----------------------------------------",
                    "Region": "us-east-1a",
                    "LogGroup": "RckWebServer",
                    "LogStream": "used our instance id-httpErr"
                }
            },
            {
                "Id": "CloudWatch",
                "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CloudWatch.CloudWatchOutputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
                "Parameters": {
                    "AccessKey": "------------------------------",
                    "SecretKey": "------------------------------",
                    "Region": "us-east-1a",
                    "NameSpace": "Windows/Default"
                }
            }
        ],
        "Flows": {
            "Flows": [
                "IISLogs,IISCloudWatchLogs",
                "HttpErrLogs,HttpCloudWatchLogs"
            ]
        }
    }
}`

> 2. Then, Configure integration with CloudWatch. Association was created successfully.
> 3. **Can't see log group in cloudwatch log console.**.
>      4.Checked the error log in this file path [C:/ProgramData/Amazon/SSM/Logs]

**Error log:**

2018-11-12 11:20:06,055 [1] INFO  [Framework] - Could not create component because configuration is missing HttpErrLogs and work flow based on this component will not start.
2018-11-12 11:20:06,077 [1] INFO  [Framework] - Could not create component because configuration is missing HttpCloudWatchLogs and work flow based on this component will not start.
2018-11-12 11:20:06,077 [1] INFO  [Framework] - Could not create component because configuration is missing HttpErrLogs and work flow based on this component will not start.
2018-11-12 11:20:06,077 [1] ERROR [Framework] - Workflow creation failed: Could not create component ID HttpErrLogs. Please verify the components in the workflow are defined in the configuration.
2018-11-12 11:20:06,077 [1] ERROR [Framework] - Could not initialize the CloudWatch plug-in with the provided configuration settings.
2018-11-12 11:20:06,077 [1] ERROR [Framework] - aws:cloudWatch plugin raised exception.
AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CloudwatchConfigurationException: Could not initialize the CloudWatch plug-in with the provided configuration settings.
Workflow creation failed: Could not create component ID HttpErrLogs. Please verify the components in the workflow are defined in the configuration.

at AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.Host.Configure(String configuration)
   at Amazon.EC2Services.Config.Plugins.CloudWatch.CloudWatchPlugin.Apply(PluginApplyContext applyContext, PluginArgs pluginArgs)
2018-11-12 11:20:06,102 [1] INFO  [Framework] - aws:cloudWatch plugin configuration verified
2018-11-12 11:20:06,102 [1] INFO  [aws:cloudWatch] - CloudWatch execution started.
2018-11-12 11:20:06,102 [1] INFO  [aws:cloudWatch] - Starting the CloudWatch plug-in
2018-11-12 11:20:06,102 [1] ERROR [aws:cloudWatch] - Host not configured, no data will be uploaded to CloudWatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ID's dont match `HttpErr`:

```
{
                "Id": "HttpErr",
                "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CustomLog.CustomLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
                "Parameters": {
                    "LogDirectoryPath": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\LogFiles\\HTTPERR",
                    "TimestampFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                    "Encoding": "UTF-8",
                    "Filter": "",
                    "CultureName": "en-US",
                    "TimeZoneKind": "UTC",
                    "LineCount": "3"
                }
            }
```

But in your Flows your using `HttpErrLogs`

```
"Flows": {
            "Flows": [
                "IISLogs,IISCloudWatchLogs",
                "HttpErrLogs,HttpCloudWatchLogs"
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Created a new association with definitions as mentioned in the flows in json and restart the SSM Agent. There is no error in the log. But I can't get the log group in CloudWatch log console.

Comment: Change `"Region": "us-east-1a"` to `"Region": "us-east-1"`. us-east-1a is an availability zone not a region.

Comment: Yeah. Got it. Now got the log group. Thank you for your response.